# How to write a PHP Program to display all the $_SERVER elements

Tags: php

Just started the class and started learning PHP. Professor asked us to write a PHP Program to display all the `$_SERVER` elements. I read the chapters and I am confused on what he wants, can someone explain?

I tried what I found in the textbook

```
<?php
//hw1.php 
//Write a PHP Program to display all the $_SERVER elements

$came_from = htmlentities($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
echo "$_SERVER";
?>
```

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a free coding service. Please take a look at the PHP manual pages for [$_SERVER](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) and [foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) as primers on the subject. I would imagine that your textbook has sections on these subjects as well.

Comment: `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` isn't reliable to use.

Comment: @Jay My recommendation for you is to continue reviewing your textbook's sections on PHP's syntax and programming basics and to go into your professor's office hours to ask for clarification on any points that are confusing. Stack Overflow isn't here to teach you programming, but to help you when you get stuck and all of your other resources are failing you. That last point is particularly important--you need to make use of the resources that are already readily available to you before giving up. You're paying an absurd amount of money for a professor to teach you. Get your money's worth.

Comment: `$_SERVER` is  super global associative array, you can dump it with `var_dump($_SERVER);` or loop throw it's elements as `$key => $value`

Answer (score 2):

If display all  of array elements

```
echo '<pre>';


print_r($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

Array convert to string

```
$string='[ ';
foreach($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] as $key=>$val)
{


$string.=$key.'=>'.$val.",\n";

}

$string.=']';


echo $string;
```

For example display $_SERVER with echo

```
string='[ ';
foreach($_SERVER as $key=>$val)
{


$string.=$key.'=>'.$val.",<br>";

}

$string.=']';


echo $string;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply do this, if you want to see it in a browser.

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_SERVER);
echo "</pre>";
```